# Combining PDFs errno 2 no such file or directory even the file exists python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm combining numerous PDF files in Python and getting the error '`errno 2 nno such file or directory`' despite the fact that the file exists.

I tried to display the PDF files just to show that the PDF file exists

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

merger = PdfFileMerger()

source_dir = os.getcwd() + '/Combined PDF'

for items in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if items.endswith('.pdf'):
        print(items)
        #merger.append(items)

#merger.write('./Combined PDF/CombinedPDF.pdf')       
#merger.close()
```

**Result**

```
PS C:\Users\RVC\Desktop\Python> & C:/Users/RVC/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe "c:/Users/RVC/Desktop/Python/Combined PDF/test.py"
PDF 1.pdf
PDF 2.pdf
PDF 3.pdf
PDF 4.pdf
```

But when I removed the comment `#` and execute it failed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\RVC\Desktop\Python\Combined PDF\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    merger.append(items)
  File "C:\Users\RVC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Users\RVC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 114, in merge
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PDF 1.pdf'
PS C:\Users\RVC\Desktop\Python>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `PDF 1.pdf` etc. which means merger expects those files to be in cwd.

Comment: the File exists in `source_dir = os.getcwd() + '/Combined PDF'`

Comment: That's not where you told the merger they are.

Comment: ok.. so how can I do that ?

Comment: Well, you seem to know how to point to a file in located in a subdirectory judging by the `merger.write('./Combined PDF/CombinedPDF.pdf')` so try to do a similiar thing to point to file `PDF 1.pdf` in `/Combined PDF` directory.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error `merger = PdfFileMerger('./Combined PDF')`

Comment: One more hint, path to your file is `./Combined PDF/PDF 1.pdf`, not `PDF 1.pdf`

Comment: still got this error .. I aleady used the variable `merger = PdfFileMerger(source_dir)` and this `merger = PdfFileMerger('./Combined PDF/')`